# Using VBA to click a button

Tags: vba, button

I am trying to pull information from a website, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to click the button. I've got the code to input the information. This is the html for the website . Any help would be appreciated.

```
<p role="button" tabindex="0" class="fmtbutton" onkeypress="finddistancebetweenaandb(document.forms['inp']['pointa'].value,document.forms['inp']['pointb'].value);" onclick="finddistancebetweenaandb(document.forms['inp']['pointa'].value,document.forms['inp']['pointb'].value);">&nbsp;Show&nbsp;</p>
```

Here is the full code that I have so far.

```
    Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
FranchiseAddress = Range("B2").Value
Movefrom = Range("B3").Value
moveto = Range("B4").Value

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm"
Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set d = .Document.getElementsByName("onoffswitch")
d.Item(0).Click
Set f = .Document.getElementsByName("pointa")
f.Item(0).Value = FranchiseAddress
Set a = .Document.getElementsByName("pointb")
a.Item(0).Value = Movefrom
```

' This is where I'm Stuck'

```
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried multiple solutions found on this site for many questions, but none of them seem to work.

Thank you.

Comment: this has been asked and answered so many times. please do research. then come back if you have code that you need help with.

Comment: I have tried many times, with multiple answers from this site. I will edit with the code that I have up to this point.

Comment: that would be good

Comment: is it on https://www.freemaptools.com ???

Comment: It is. Is there already an answer for that one? If so, can you point me to it?

Comment: no, i just searched for `finddistancebetweenaandb`

Comment: That gets it without the "ie" on the front!! Thank you so Much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your code

```
Dim aaa As Object
Set aaa = .Document.getElementsByClassName("fmtbutton") ' this returns 4 objects, your button is the first one
aaa(0).Click
```

Comment: `aaa(1).Click`  toggles fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

You can be a little more elegant and target the attribute with a CSS selector:

```
.document.querySelector("[role=button]").Click
```

The `attribute = value` selector, `[role=button]`, looks for an element with attribute `role` whose value is `button`. There is only one on the page so no loop needed.